# A better architecture then if(something) DoIt() else Dont()

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, api, infrastructure

I'm trying to create a mechanism that will allow the application to decide (in runtime) whether to execute some functionality.

"Some Functionality" can be anything, it can be c# code which is contained in several classes in several dlls, it can be UI, it can be database query execution, etc.

Most importantly, it should fit in the current existing infrastructure I have, which I cannot re-design and build from scratch.

The more I think of it, it seems like the only solution I can use would be to hold some table which will be the "functionality repository" and it will tell (by unique key) if a functionality is on / off.

Then in code, I will have to place in each spot which handles such functionality an if else statement.

E.g.

```
If(functionalityEnabled)?
DoFunctionality()
Else
DoTheUsusal()
```

Is there a better way or a better design to implement it? I would like to keep the solution as simple as possible, but on the other hand, this solution  is really ugly and will eventually make my code looks like spaghetti code.

Your thoughts will be appreciated,
I'm using c# with sql server, web api for web services.

Edit:

I want to say that I appreciate the time and effort of everyone answering my question, there were some really interesting ideas that you brought up.
I eventually marked @dasblinkenlight answer since it suited by need the best, though other answers here are really good and may be useful to others.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this `if-else` being used multiple times in your code? Is that the problem?

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly - are you actually looking for some kind of plugin architecture?

Comment: A programmer goes to sleep, and puts two glasses on his nightstand: one glass with water in case he gets thirsty at night, and one empty glass in case he doesn't.

Comment: Yuval: It's a problem because it will make the code hard to maintain, conider a class which had over 10 functionalities I should be able to turn on and off. this means at least 10 different if statements, and more if I encounter dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A once-popular quip among OO programmers has been that every conditional in the code indicate a missed opportunity to subclass. Although this rule is far from being universal, and it falls short when it comes to composition, there is a grain of truth to it, especially when you see the same condition popping up in multiple `if`s across different methods of the same class.

A common way of dealing with `if`s like that is using some combination of inheritance and composition, and moving the decision to a single place where your object is being created.

The inheritance way looks like this:

```
interface Doer {
    void doSomething();
}
class BasicDoer implements Doer {
    public void doSomething() {
        ...
    }
}
class EnhancedDoer extends BasicDoer {
    public void doSomething() {
        base.doSomething();
        ...
    }
}

// At construction time:

Doer doer;
if (someCondition)
    doer = new BasicDoer();
else
    doer = new EnhancedDoer();
```

The composition way looks like this:

```
interface Doer {
    void doSomething();
}
// Create several implementations of Activity, then...

// At construction time:
List<Doer> doers = new ArrayList<>();
if (someCondition1)
    doers.add(new SomeKindOfDoer());
if (someCondition2)
    doers.add(new AnotherKindOfDoer());
if (someCondition3)
    doers.add(new YetAnotherKindOfDoer());
```

Now instead of an `if` you do this:

```
for (Doer d : doers) {
    d.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: +1 that's an interesting idea, i'll try to challenge it with the current implementation of infrastructure I'm handling and let you know if this may work.

Comment: Since you used the interface, subclassing is not needed to make this work, although it may help you save code in the implementation of the enhanced doer, of course.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two classes that implement the same interface, your application can call the functionality (methods, properties) of the class without knowing exactly if it is calling the basic functionality or the alternative functionality:

```
IFunctionalityX {
  DoIt();
}

class BasicFunctionalityX: IFunctionalityX {
  public DoIt() {
    // Default behaviour goes here
  }
}

class PluginFunctionalityX: IFunctionalityX {
  public DoIt() {
    // Alternative functionality.
  }
}
```

If PluginFunctionalityX shares parts of its implementation with BasicFunctionalityX, you may inherit it from the other, but whether you do or not doesn't really matter. As long as you use the interface, that is what counts, and you can use this method regardless of whether the classes are related or not.

In the initialization of your program, you can make the decision once and create an instance of the right class. You may store this class in some container that holds all your functionalities. FunctionalityX is a property of interface IFunctionalityX, and you can make other interfaces (and properties) for other functionalities.

```
if (functionalityXEnabled) {
  FunctionalityContainer.FunctionalityX = new PluginFunctionality();
} else {
  FunctionalityContainer.FunctionalityX = new BasicFunctionality();
}
```

Then, in the rest of your application, you can call your functionality through:

```
FunctionalityContainer.FunctionalityX.DoIt();
```

Instead of implementing this from scratch you may use a *dependancy injection* library, like [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn223671(v=pandp.30).aspx). This also allows you to more easily get an instance of the right functionality at the time you need it without having to create them all at the start of your program, and without writing elaborate constructor code for all fucntionalities.

Comment: +1 for suggestion use of DI framework with interfaces solution. this however will require me to modify architecture in some components which I can't do so DI is not an option. In addition what happends if a class contains several functionalities? how will DoIt behave in such scenario? as I will need to distinguish it.

Comment: Make an interface for each distinct functionality. If a class implements multiple functionalities, it can implement multiple interfaces. `DoIt` was just an example name. It's better to use a better name. For instance, default functionality is save to MyDocuments, but if enabled it can save to OneDrive, so the interface could `ISave`, containing a method `Save(fileName)`. This interface is implemented by a SaveToOneDrive class, and by your default class which may implement more than just ISave. Note though, that it's often better to limit the responsibilities of a class too.

Answer (score 2):

You want to dispatch your code differently at runtime dependent on a configuration setting. Conditionals and polymorphism are two ways of doing so.

## Conditionals

At runtime, check for values using `if`, `switch` or other lookup methods. You're already doing these.

```
if (configFile.cloudAccount == null) {
    saveFileToDisk();
} else saveFileToCloud();
```

### Advantages

- They're conditionals, you really can't avoid having to do one at some point in any nontrivial development project

### Disadvantages

- Doing them at *every* point in your application would be painful, though. So they're best combined with other strategies to minimise their use

## Polymorphism

When loading your application, read through the configuration file and construct your application's components accordingly:

```
interface IFileSaver { /* Used to save files in your application */ }

class DiskSaver : IFileSaver { /* The default file saving class */ }

class CloudSaver : IFileSaver { /* If they've configured a cloud account */ }

// EXAMPLE USE

int Main (...) {
    // Setup your application, load a config file. 
    // You'll need to check the config with a conditional 
    // here (uh oh) but other components of your application 
    // will just use the IFileSaver interface
    if (configFile.cloudAccount != null) {
        YourApplication.FileSaver = new CloudSaver(configFile.cloudAccount);
    } else {
        YourApplication.FileSaver = new DiskSaver();
    }
}

// Somewhere else in your application
void SaveCurrentDocument() {
    // No if's needed, it was front loaded when initialising
    // the application
    YourApplication.FileSaver.Save();
}
```

### Advantages

- Fits in nicely with object-oriented design
- All your configuration checks are front loaded. After loading in the correct classes the rest of your program will use them, oblivious to their actual implementation. Because of that, you don't need to do `if` checks throughout your code.
- Compiler will be able to statically check type errors in your approach

## Disadvantages

- Only as flexible as your class's interface. Maybe you want some extra steps and checks to occur with a `CloudSaver`, they'd better fit into the pre-existing interface; otherwise, they won't happen.

Long story short - conditionals let you explicitly perform the checks whenever they're needed so, in principle, you get a lot of procedural flexibility. For example, maybe the `SaveAs` routine needs to save files *slightly* differently than the `Save` routine. However, as you've identified, this leads to long repetitive code. In those cases, structuring your code to use polymorphism might help out.

Either way, you will almost certainly need to have *some* amount of conditional checks wherever there is flexibility in your application.

Note: There are *many* other ways of achieving runtime config checks, I'm just pointing out the most common (and usually straightforward)

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a single condition then you have no choice but to use `if else` and is perfect for single conditions.

If you have more then 1 condition, you may think of using Switch statement.

As far as you are worried about your code going to look complicated with if else statement, put your code within functions,

```
if(condition)
{
  DoThis();
}
else
{
  DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: Switch statements are the same, it's the same solution as far as I'm concerned. I'm actually looking for a better design then the current suggested one (assuming multiple if statements can occur)

Comment: without looking at any code, my advise would be to stop worrying about if & else or switch statements, they don't really make your code ugly or smell bad (MOST Times), so focus on overall structure of your code, post some code here to get the best advise

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something similar to [strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (incapsulation of behaviour) will make it more managable if functionality doesn't require lots of interaction with object data (though interaction is possible). Pros: readable extendable code, cons: lots of code.

```
namespace SomethingLikeStrategy
{
  public interface Behaviour {
    void doThis();
    void changeM(ref int m);
    void doThat();
  }

  public class BehaviourOriginal : Behaviour {
    public void doThis() {
      Console.WriteLine("foo");
    }
    public void changeM(ref int m) {
      m = 20;
    }
    public void doThat() {
      throw new Exception("not implemented");
    }
  }

  public class BehaviourSpecial : Behaviour {
    public void doThis() {
      Console.WriteLine("bar");
    }
    public void changeM(ref int m) {
      m = 10;
    }
    public void doThat() {
      throw new Exception("not implemented");
    }
  }

  public class MyClass {

    Behaviour mBehaviour;
    int mM = 0;

    public MyClass() {
      mBehaviour = new BehaviourOriginal();
    }

    public void setSpecialBehaviour(bool special) {
      if (special) {
        mBehaviour = new BehaviourSpecial();
      } else {
        mBehaviour = new BehaviourOriginal();
      }
    }

    public void doThis() {
      mBehaviour.doThis();
    }

    public void doThat() {
      mBehaviour.doThat();
    }

    public void changeM() {
      mBehaviour.changeM(ref mM);
    }

    public void printM() {
      Console.WriteLine(mM);
    }

  }

  class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
      myClass.doThis();
      myClass.setSpecialBehaviour(true);
      myClass.doThis();

      myClass.setSpecialBehaviour(false);
      myClass.printM();
      myClass.changeM();
      myClass.printM();
      myClass.setSpecialBehaviour(true);
      myClass.changeM();
      myClass.printM();

      Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
      Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
  }
}
```